# How do I populate values of a static QMap in C++ Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have this in my C++ header file:

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QString>

class LogEvent {

public:
    LogEvent();

    enum column_t {TIMESTAMP_COLUMN = 0, TYPE_COLUMN = 1, EVENT_COLUMN = 2,
        FILE_COLUMN = 3};
    static QMap<column_t, QString> COLUMN_NAMES;

    static QMap<column_t, QString> getColumnNames() {
        return LogEvent::COLUMN_NAMES;
    }

    //blah blah blah other functions
};
```

This is my C++ source file:

```
#include "LogEvent.h"

LogEvent::LogEvent()
{
    //constructor code
}

//blah blah blah other functions
```

I want to add values to my static QMap COLUMN_NAMES. Where and how would I do this?

Comment: Time for Qt to add some C++11 support!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use static function that returns initialized map:

```
// source file:
QMap<column_t, QString> LogEvent::initColumnNames() {
    QMap<column_t, QString> map;
    map.insert(LogEvent::TIMESTAMP_COLUMN,"Timestamp");
    // and so on
    return map;
}

QMap<column_t, QString> LogEvent::COLUMN_NAMES = initColumnNames();
```

Also, in case you want to use strings internationalization in static variables and need to call `QTextCodec::setCodecForTr` first, it is a good idea to move static variable into its getter function:

```
class LogEvent {

public:
// ...
    static QMap<column_t, QString> initColumnNames();

    static QMap<column_t, QString> getColumnNames() {
        static QMap<column_t, QString> COLUMN_NAMES = initColumnNames();
        return COLUMN_NAMES;
    }
}
```

This way `COLUMN_NAMES` will be initialized with the first call of `getColumnNames()` and you can set the text codec beforehand. But this is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks!. Quick question about thread safe. When you say that this function is no thread safe, you mean that if my application is multi-threaded, there could be issues correct?

Comment: Yes, issues could appear when several threads execute non thread-safe code simultaneously. Generally, to solve this problem you can use [synchronization objects](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/threads-synchronizing.html) like `QMutex`. But in this particular case you just need to guaranty that static variable is initialized when only one thread is active, since it's not supposed to be modified.

Answer (score 52):

In the meantime, Qt 5.2 added support for C++11 initializer lists in QMap:

```
QMap::​QMap(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Key, T> > list)
```

This means you can initialize your map like this:

```
static QMap<QString, int> my_map{{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}};
```

Comment: I just tried this approach and it doesn't compile, in same time all otehr C++11 features works.... lambdas etc, are you sure it actually implemented? I'm  using QT5.3.1

error: no matching function for call to 'QMap<QString, int>::QMap(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

Comment: I actually only tried this with Qt 5.4.0, but the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#QMap-2) says it's available since Qt 5.1. Did you enable C++11 properly by adding `CONFIG += c++11` to the .pro file?

Comment: For completeness: if the map had been declared elsewhere, you can initialize it with something like: `this->m_map = QMap<QString, int>( { {"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3} } );`

Comment: This is not optimal way since inserting single pair of <int, CustomStruct> (for both std::map and QMap) generates 1 constructor of CustomStruct, two constructor copies, and two destructors. If you use method of static function, that `userr1728854` mentioned, it will generate only one constructor, one constructor copy and one destructor.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach using an initializer list.

```
QMap<QString, QString> qmap_(std::map<QString, QString> {{ "", "" }});
```

This works for older Qt before Qt was fixed to work with initializer lists directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create std::map and use it to init QMap, or just replace QMap with std::map:

```
 static const std::pair<T1, T2> arr[] = { 
     std::pair<T1, T2>(v1, v2),
     std::pair<T1, T2>(v3, v4),
};

static std::map<T1, T2> my_map(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
QMap<column_t, QString> LogEvent::COLUMN_NAMES(my_map);
```

Another way is init COLUMN_NAMES in constructor:

```
LogEvent::LogEvent() {
   if (COLUMN_NAMES.isEmpty())
     ;//init it here
```

but this is not thread safe, the first one method was called before main, while the second during may be called during runtime.

Comment: Should the first method be in the header or source file?